# Fetch data from table by skipping records based on date time interval

Tags: mysql

I have tracklog table in mysql which has various fields including datetime field.

tracklog_data

```
id  pos_datetime
1   2015-05-05 12:04:50 
2   2015-05-05 12:04:30 
3   2015-05-05 12:04:10
4   2015-05-05 12:03:40
5   2015-05-05 12:03:20  
6   2015-05-05 12:03:05
7   2015-05-05 12:03:01
8   2015-05-05 12:02:42
9   2015-05-05 12:02:20
10  2015-05-05 12:01:30
```

Now i want to fetch this records but what I want is that it should fetch only one record for particular minute. 
For example in give table it should first take `id` with `1` then it should skip all the next records having same minute so it should skip record with `id 2 3` since its hour and minute matching with `id 1` i.e. 12 hour 4 minute. Then it should fetch record with `id 4` since its minute is different and skip all next record with 12 hour and 3 minute and move to 12 hour and 2 minute.

so in the end output should be

```
id  pos_datetime
1   2015-05-05 12:04:50
4   2015-05-05 12:03:40
8   2015-05-05 12:02:42
10  2015-05-05 12:01:30
```

Please help me guys...Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT id, pos_datetime, val
FROM mytable 
WHERE id IN (
   SELECT MIN(id)
   FROM mytable
   GROUP BY DATE(pos_datetime), 
            HOUR(pos_datetime), 
            MINUTE(pos_datetime) )
```

`GROUP BY` clause of the sub-query places inside the same group all records having the same Date, Hour and Minute. `MIN(id)` simply returns the record having the minimum `id` value per group.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1cdbc9/1)

You can alternatively perform `INNER JOIN` with the derived table of the sub-query:

```
SELECT m.id, pos_datetime, val
FROM mytable AS m
INNER JOIN (SELECT MIN(id) AS id
            FROM mytable
            GROUP BY DATE(pos_datetime), 
                     HOUR(pos_datetime), 
                     MINUTE(pos_datetime)) t
ON m.id = t.id
```

`val` field has been added just for demonstrational purposes.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1cdbc9/5)

Comment: In your answer, for the id=1 its getting pos_datetime of id=3.

Comment: @Ullas I have fixed this issue.

Comment: Ok try your answer sir...@GiorgosBetsos

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos sry for inconvenience but can you please tell me what if I have to skip 2 3 minutes and then fetch next record it would be gr8 help

Comment: @eLemEnt Well, that's a completely different requirement that cannot be answered in terms a comment. Try posting a new question perhaps?

Comment: Ok sir http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30796337/fetch-data-from-table-by-skipping-records-based-on-minute link to new question

Comment: @eLemEnt Well, it's not that different after all. You can create, for example, 3 minute time slots using integer and modulo division. Check [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/57fcc/8).