# Fetch data from table by skipping records based on minute

Tags: mysql

I have tracklog table in mysql which has various fields including datetime field.

tracklog_data

```
id  pos_datetime
1   2015-05-05 12:08:50 
2   2015-05-05 12:08:30 
3   2015-05-05 12:07:40
4   2015-05-05 12:07:20
5   2015-05-05 12:07:10  
6   2015-05-05 12:06:05
7   2015-05-05 12:06:01
8   2015-05-05 12:05:30
9   2015-05-05 12:05:10
10  2015-05-05 12:04:30
11  2015-05-05 12:04:20
12  2015-05-05 12:03:50 
13  2015-05-05 12:03:20
14  2015-05-05 12:02:50
15  2015-05-05 12:02:40
16  2015-05-05 12:02:10
17  2015-05-05 12:01:40
18  2015-05-05 12:01:10
19  2015-05-05 12:01:05
20  2015-05-05 12:00:30
21  2015-05-05 11:59:30
```

I want data minute wise that means if there are two records having same minute then only first one should come skipping all the other records having same hour and minute. Then it should also skip next two minutes records and move to third minute and do the same further on

so for example I need timelimit to skip is 2 minute suppose

```
id  pos_datetime
1   2015-05-05 12:08:30
8   2015-05-05 12:05:30
14  2015-05-05 12:02:50
21  2015-05-05 11:59:30
```

Please help I will be glad..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30795789/552116

Answer (score 0):

You can use DATE(), HOUR(), MINUTE().

For example:

```
SELECT Id, Pos_Datetime
FROM Dummy 
WHERE Id IN (
    SELECT MIN(Id)
    FROM Dummy
    GROUP BY DATE(Pos_Datetime), HOUR(Pos_Datetime), MINUTE(Pos_Datetime));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, pos_datetime
FROM mytable 
WHERE id IN (
SELECT MIN(id)
FROM mytable 
GROUP BY 
ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(pos_datetime)/(1 * 60)))
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c4a30/1)